# In-App purchases with Parse.com - Non-renewing subscriptions

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, in-app-purchase

I'm trying to implement non-renewing subscriptions into my iOS application, using the Parse SDK (because i'm using it for push notifications).

I thought it would be easy, but no, because Apple is not handling subscriptions periods on his side...

I found on the archived parse.com forum ([here the link](https://parse.com/questions/in-app-purchase-non-renewing-subscription-on-parse)) that they were planning to implement non-renewing subscriptions into PFPurchase, but it was two years ago. Is it implemented right now ? Are they still planning to implement it ? I'm finding nothing in the Parse documentation.

It would be nice if they were an API to handle all this easily... Because it's very hard for a beginner like me !

I'm only finding outdated tutorials for now...

Do you know any easy-to-use API for non-renewing subscriptions ?

Comment: I'm looking into this as well. What have you learned?

Answer (score 0):

Why not using NSUserDefaults to store the date, and iCloud to restore? IT isn't really that hard to build yourself.